# Batch Insert yii2 from checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox, yii2

Basically I have tow models in one form, and I have an array value from checkbox.
This is my form :

**Model 1**

```
$dataConditionContainer = ArrayHelper::map(ItemConditionIr::find()->all(), 'id', 'nama_condition');
echo $form->field($modelLinkItemConditionIrToIr, 'condition_id')->label("Container")->inline()->checkBoxList($dataConditionContainer);
```

**Model2**

```
<?= $form->field($modelInspectionReport, 'vehicle_no')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

Now, from Model 1 that interprated by checkbox give me an array like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

I want to insert them using batch insert, but this array need a value from model2 primary key like `$inspectionReport = $modelInspectionReport->id`.

Now How to make a batch insert ?
I know like this :

```
 $connection->createCommand()->batchInsert('link_item_condition_ir_to_ir',
       ['inspection_id', 'condition_id'], checkboxarraysuitable)->execute();
```

Is yii2 provide this ?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->batchInsert(ItemConditionIr::tableName(), [
                            'inspection_id',
                            'condition_id',
                        ], [[1,2], [3,4]])
                        ->execute();

Comment: Can you explain a bit?

Comment: batchInsert($table, $columns, $rows )
$table: your table name (ex: 'user')
$columns: an array of columns you want to insert to
$rows: an multidimensional array of row to be batch inserted into

this may help: [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#batchInsert()-detail)

Answer (score 0):

Your `$checkboxarraysuitable` array is not properly structured. Your `array` must be in `array of arrays` structure. [Here is an example of using BatchInsert()](http://www.devprofessor.com/yii2/use-yii2-batch-insert/) with proper `array` structure.